# Dynamically change a links structure

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello users i am basically wanting to change the structure of the link in hand.

I am using `<?= $_GET['content'] ?>` to catch the content items.

The code listed below is what i tried using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond   
RewriteRule ^/$ live.php?content=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't work.

example,

old -> domain.com/live.php?content=username

new -> domain.com/username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /live.php?content=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: where does the 2nd group (`$2`) come from ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear but I guess what you need is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /live.php?content=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /username was not found on this server.